# How use Objective-c method in my Swift Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, objective-c-swift-bridge

Hello I want to use this method inside my swift class, already create the header, but I only manage to access the method (setApiKey). this is the code in objective c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class CLQResponseHeaders, CLQError;
@class CLQToken;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface Culqi : NSObject

/**
 * gets singleton object.
 * @return singleton
 */
+ (Culqi *_Nonnull)sharedInstance;

+ (void)setApiKey:(NSString *_Nonnull)apiKey;

#pragma mark - Tokens

- (void)createTokenWithCardNumber:(NSString *_Nonnull)cardNumber
                              cvv:(NSString *_Nonnull)cvv
                  expirationMonth:(NSString *_Nonnull)expirationMonth
                   expirationYear:(NSString *_Nonnull)expirationYear
                            email:(NSString *_Nonnull)email
                         metadata:(NSDictionary * _Nullable)metadata
                          success:(void (^_Nullable)(CLQResponseHeaders *_Nonnull responseHeaders, CLQToken * _Nonnull token))success
                          failure:(void (^_Nullable)(CLQResponseHeaders *_Nonnull responseHeaders, CLQError * _Nonnull businessError, NSError * _Nonnull error))failure;

@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

My swift code is

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RegisterController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //THIS METHOD CALL SUCCESS
        Culqi.setApiKey("")


    }

}
```

Update: the method setApiKey is accessible, what happens is that I can not call the method "createTokenWithCardNumber"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: If my class is accessible, what happens is that I can not access this method
(createTokenWithCardNumber)

Comment: @DacDevs I think, this is your Imlementation (.m) file code. right?  You need to move method declaration to (.h) header file.

Comment: Yes in my implementation file is right, this code is in objective-c for execute the method, but in swift not call `[[Culqi sharedInstance] createTokenWithCardNumber:
}];`

Comment: The documentation is here, https://github.com/culqi/culqi-ios

Comment: Try this: Culqi.sharedInstance().createTokenWithCardNumber(#<your parameter arguments>#)

Comment: You need to import Culqi modul in you controller before calling any function. Write @import Culqi in RegisterController and after that you can call Culqi function.

Comment: @DacDevs I am facing the same problem, my swift instance methods declared with objc is not visible in Objective C file.  have you find any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Declare your function/method `setApiKey` in header file of your Objective-C class.

```
// Move following line/code to header file (.h) of your objective-c class
+ (void)setApiKey:(NSString *_Nonnull)apiKey;
```

Your method `createTokenWithCardNumber` is an instance method (not a class method), you need to create an instance of your class to access it. Try this,

```
let c = Culqi()
c.createTokenWithCardNumber(#<your parameter arguments>#)

// or use shared instance
Culqi.sharedInstance().createTokenWithCardNumber(#<your parameter arguments>#)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have already created the Bridging-Header.h file and are importing the class correctly

Comment: the method setApiKey is accessible, what happens is that I can not call the method "createTokenWithCardNumber"

Comment: @DacDevs what was the corrected class? could you share?